# Problema para importar Gson en android 4.2

Tags: android, android-studio, gson, importación

He actualizado la versión de android studio de **4.1** a **4.2** y me ha dejado de reconocer la librería Gson.

En el build.gradle a nivel app lo tengo declarado asi.

dependencies {

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

}

En la clase que lo uso tengo puesto asi:

import com.google.gson.Gson;

Pero me dice **Cannot resolve symbol 'Gson'**

**Aclaro que en la version 4.1 de android studio andaba lo mas bien.**

Comment: Solo cambiaste la versión de Gson o también otras dependencias? posiblemente el error se encuentre en tu código al cambiar otras dependencias

Comment: @Jorgesys Solo actualice el IDE de android studio a 4.2. No hice ningún cambio en el proyecto. Así mismo me dejo de reconocer la librería Gson.

Comment: has un rebuild project (Build > Rebuild Project) y revisa el output. Ahí tiene que decir cual es el problema. Si agregas eso a tu pregunta podremos ayudarte

Comment: Ok @Franco esto es algo común cuanto se actualiza la IDE , invalida cache y reinicia, revisa la respuesta que agregué.

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem Hice lo que me dijiste y el output sale sin ningún error.

Comment: @Jorgesys Fue lo primero q hice al ver que no me tomaba el import. De todas formas intente de nuevo y sigo en la misma. No me reconoce la libreria Gson.

**Agrego por si sirve: acabo de desinstalar la versión 4.2.1 de android studio y volví a la 4.1.3. Ahora anda nuevamente.**

ME HACE RENEGAR LA VERSION 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Si tu proyecto funcionaba sin problema y realizaste una actualización de Android Studio , regularmente volver a construir el proyecto con `Build` > `Rebuild Project` no funciona, en este caso debes invalidar cache, ve a `File` > `Invalidates Cache / Restart`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]